# Switch Button is not changing

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
class _PageOne extends State<Page> {
  bool notifications = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        drawer: Drawer(),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SwitchListTile(
                  title: Text("Allow Notifications"),
                  secondary: Icon(Icons.notifications_active),
                  value: notifications,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    notifications = val;
                    print(notifications);
                  })
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `setState` on `onChanged`

Comment: When asking a question here, you need to be clear and describe the problem in the **post body** and ask a **specific question**. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
onChanged: (bool val) {
        setState(() {
          notifications = val; 
          print(notifications);
        });
      },
```

As mentioned in the comments by [esentis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12413404/esentis) you need `setState(){}` so that the widget will rebuild itself when a change happens.

Answer (score 0):

Assign notification to value inside the body of setState meanwhile call setState I hope you understand